# COMException in debug mode only in VS2010 when using MS HTML Objects library

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, com, mshtml

I am using Microsoft HTML Objects library in my project, and the problem is, that I always get an exception when I try to start in VS debugger (I got COMException with E_FAIL HRESULT). When I start application without debug - it works nicely.

I tried to run this project on other computers, and it works, even in debugging mode, both on 64-bit and 32-bit Windows. I reinstalled .NET Framework, installed VS2010 Service Pack 1, but no use. Have anyone encoutered such problem?

Comment: Yesterday I encountered interesting thing. The problem is very connected with the user. If I create a new user on the machine - the problem **is gone**. So the cause is somwhere in temporary files or the register.